# Rounded Material Icons border and color problem

Tags: css, material-design, google-material-icons

I have included Material Icons Rounded to my webpage like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I have css code for rounded class

```
.material-icons.material-icons--rounded {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
}
```

In the page, star icon looks like this:

[image]

If i increase the font-size it turns into this:

[image]

Where does that border coming from and how to remove it ?

Edit: I have created a pen to reproduce the problem https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wOJdMZ

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Round";
.material-icons--rounded {
  font-family: "Material Icons Round";
}
i {
   color: red;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.size--2 {
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Rounded</th>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded">star</i></td>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded size--2">star</i></td>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded">star_half</i></td>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded size--2">star_half</i></td>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded">star_border</i></td>
    <td><i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded size--2">star_border</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Not Rounded<br>
      <td><i class="material-icons">star</i></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons size--2">star</i></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons">star_half</i></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons size--2">star_half</i></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons">star_border</i></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons size--2">star_border</i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** 
*Rounded icon colors are not changing on some screen sizes.*

I have updated the code snippet which is attached to the question.

- On the 1920x1080 monitor, all icons are red.
- On the 2560 x 1600 macbook retina screen, rounded icons are black and the others are red. (This doesn't seem to be a problem on Chrome or Firefox)

**UPDATE 2**

The color problem is not solved. **On the retina screens icons are not getting any color. 
They are always black.**
[image: Code snippet picture on my Macbook Pro]
Need help about that.

Comment: Can you provide the related HTML/CSS so it can be analyzed a bit easier? Without context it becomes a bit hard to debug this

Comment: Sure, I added a codepen link

Comment: Thanks, the `<i>` tag is setting a 1px border. You can remove it like this: `i { border: 0; }`for all the <i> tags or make it more specific by adding `.material-icons { border: 0;}` to your stylesheet

Comment: @BillieBobbel I updated the pen again. It seems `<i>` doesn't get's a border.

Comment: Yeah, my bad... Codepen got confused by a missing semicolon; But it seems @yunzen figured out it was due to a borked glyph...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the glyph itself

If you download the SVG glyphs from here
https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=star&style=round
and here https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=star&style=round

you can see the [rounded glyph](https://material.io/tools/icons/static/icons/round-star-24px.svg) is wrong and the [pointy star](https://material.io/tools/icons/static/icons/round-star_border-24px.svg) is correct

You should file an issue to https://github.com/material-components

#### some info to the material team

The path is `path("M 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 V 0 Z m 0 0 h 24 v 24 H 0 V 0 Z m 12 17.27 l 4.15 2.51 c 0.76 0.46 1.69 -0.22 1.49 -1.08 l -1.1 -4.72 l 3.67 -3.18 c 0.67 -0.58 0.31 -1.68 -0.57 -1.75 l -4.83 -0.41 l -1.89 -4.46 c -0.34 -0.81 -1.5 -0.81 -1.84 0 L 9.19 8.63 l -4.83 0.41 c -0.88 0.07 -1.24 1.17 -0.57 1.75 l 3.67 3.18 l -1.1 4.72 c -0.2 0.86 0.73 1.54 1.49 1.08 l 4.15 -2.5 Z");`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 24 24" wtx-context="97FAD225-6CA6-4D16-A578-52C0523A648F"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0zm0 0h24v24H0V0zm12 17.27l4.15 2.51c.76.46 1.69-.22 1.49-1.08l-1.1-4.72 3.67-3.18c.67-.58.31-1.68-.57-1.75l-4.83-.41-1.89-4.46c-.34-.81-1.5-.81-1.84 0L9.19 8.63l-4.83.41c-.88.07-1.24 1.17-.57 1.75l3.67 3.18-1.1 4.72c-.2.86.73 1.54 1.49 1.08l4.15-2.5z"/></svg>
```

but should be `path("M 12 17.27 l 4.15 2.51 c 0.76 0.46 1.69 -0.22 1.49 -1.08 l -1.1 -4.72 l 3.67 -3.18 c 0.67 -0.58 0.31 -1.68 -0.57 -1.75 l -4.83 -0.41 l -1.89 -4.46 c -0.34 -0.81 -1.5 -0.81 -1.84 0 L 9.19 8.63 l -4.83 0.41 c -0.88 0.07 -1.24 1.17 -0.57 1.75 l 3.67 3.18 l -1.1 4.72 c -0.2 0.86 0.73 1.54 1.49 1.08 l 4.15 -2.5 Z")`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 24 24" wtx-context="97FAD225-6CA6-4D16-A578-52C0523A648F"><path d="M 12 17.27 l 4.15 2.51 c 0.76 0.46 1.69 -0.22 1.49 -1.08 l -1.1 -4.72 l 3.67 -3.18 c 0.67 -0.58 0.31 -1.68 -0.57 -1.75 l -4.83 -0.41 l -1.89 -4.46 c -0.34 -0.81 -1.5 -0.81 -1.84 0 L 9.19 8.63 l -4.83 0.41 c -0.88 0.07 -1.24 1.17 -0.57 1.75 l 3.67 3.18 l -1.1 4.72 c -0.2 0.86 0.73 1.54 1.49 1.08 l 4.15 -2.5 Z"/></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, [I have opened an issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/913), I hope they will fix it soon

Comment: I `+1`ed this issue

Comment: Updated the question Sir, probably there is another bug about rounded icon colors.

Comment: @Solhan I don't see your second issue. Are you sure, you didn't fork the pen?

Comment: I didn't update the pen, I updated the code snippet attached to the question.

Comment: @Solhan Ah, sorry, my bad! But I don't get the issue in the snippet on my Windows 10 in latest Chrome and in latest Firefox

Comment: Actually I didn't notice issue too on my Windows 10 with Chrome. But when I open the page with my Macbook with retina screen I saw the icons are always black. Could it be related to retina screen ? Because I I have changed the screen size on Chrome Developer Tools but it still same.

Comment: I tested on crosbrowsertesting.com on a MacOS X 10.14, Safari 12, 2560x1600 and still got only red stars

Comment: I took a picture of my screen [image](https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/8/a8224065190cfcad07b92bbf5bc72c6c-full.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was... you added font-size to both classes.
I replaced it with a new class `size--1`

```
.size--1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}
.size--2 {
  font-size: 90px;
}
.material-icons--rounded {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Round;
}
```

material-icons class didn't need that style... (he is applying the icon, if I understood right)

HTML:

```
<i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded size--1">star</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons--rounded size--2">star</i>
```

---

Saw the updated pen... 
I've tried

```
outline: none !important;
border: none !important; 
box-shadow: none !important;
```

None of these worked... 

And star becomes to square, starting from font-size: 67px... even `transform: scale(2,2)` didn't helped. Something wrong with `rounded` class))

Comment: Thank you, but if we add `.material-icons--rounded` class to the end, icons doesnt rounding